# How do I filter a list through a lookup dictionary in jinja2

Tags: python, sql, jinja2

How can I filter a list in jinja2 to generate a list of values from a lookup table?

I have a situation where I am using Jinja2 to generate SQL. I have a list of values and I want to replace them with a list of transformed values based on a lookup:

```
start_values = ['a', 'c']
lookup_table = {
    'a': {
        'table_x': '11111',
        'table_y': '22222'
    },
    'b': {
        'table_x': '33333',
        'table_y': '44444'
    },
    'c': {
        'table_x': '55555',
        'table_y': '66666'
    }
}
```

In my template, I want to be able to use do something like this using filters instead of a loop:

```
GROUP BY
{% for col in start_values %}
  {{ lookup_table[col]['table_x'] }},
{% endif %}
```

The trailing comma will lead to SQL that is not well formed.

I want to avoid creating a customer filter, but I haven't come across a filter that can find a dictionary reference the way I need:

```
{{ start_values|some_lookup_method(lookup_table)|map(attribute='table_x')|join(', ') }}
```

I can't use `map(attribute=*)` for `some_lookup_method` because I don't know how to access the key that comes from `start_values`. Most examples online are for Ansible and use a flattened structure, like the one below. I do not want that structure so please no answers for that format.

```
# Answers for this format are already plentiful on the Internet
lookup_table = [
    {
        'name': 'a',
        'table_x': '11111',
        'table_y': '22222'
    },
    # ...
]
```

Comment: Can you post the jinja that produces the result with the comma problem so all I have to do is modify it for you? EDIT:  nevermind, I was going to suggest what @Ben suggested! Note: you can set another loop variable if you are nesting

Comment: Setting another loop variable feels too noisy for me. I went with the loop.last approach. Being able to use a filter would have been nice through as having less templating would have been a lot clearer. I want to minimize customer filters though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, sadly, no such a filter in native Jinja to filter a dictionary or to make a list out of a dictionary, like the answers you found for Ansible, that are using `dict2items`.

This said, using [`loop.last`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for), you could conditionally add the comma or not:

```
GROUP BY
{%- for col in start_values %}
  {{ lookup_table[col].table_x }}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Would give you

```sql
GROUP BY
  11111,
  55555
```